# Запустить Word средствами javascript и передать в него текст

Tags: javascript, ms-word, blob

Ответ скорее всего я уже знаю, но мало ли (вдруг чего не знаю).
Есть страница с javascript. Средствами javascript формирую html-страницу, которую пользователь сохраняет (средствами же javascript) как doc-файл на своем компьютере, потом открывает его.
Функция примерно такая (выдран кусок из рабочего кода):

```
    var saveData = (function () {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = 'display: none';
        return function (data, fileName) {
            var content = data,
            blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'application/msword'}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                a.remove();
            }
        };
    }());

    var data = doc_file;
    var fileName = 'Направление.doc';
    saveData(data, fileName);
```

Можно ли каким-нибудь образом сделать так, чтобы файл не сохранялся на компьютере пользователя, а запускался Word и в него передавался текст? Работать это будет НЕ в Internet Explorer (в хромиуме), поэтому ActiveX тут не пройдет. Беда в том, что очень много файлов создается (по мере работы в программе) и плюс лишнее движение по "Сохранить" и "Открыть" - время работы оператора критично.
Догадываюсь, что нельзя, но мало ли, может какой хитрый способ есть?

Comment: Хитрый способ есть, но не со стоороны браузера. Если у вас там оператор, что подразумевает подконтрольность клиентской машины, то сделайте скрипт (bat или cmd), который будет открывать файлы в какой-либо директории.

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, спасибо за наводку - машина действительно подконтрольная. Набросал простенький скрипт, все работает как часы. Жаль только, что теперь придется каждое утро оператору bat-ник стартовать, но, думаю, это не столь критично. Скрипт кинул в ответы.

Comment: Если работает, то можете опубликовать как ответ. Может, кому-то в будущем поможет)

Comment: Да, опубликовал. Не успел ДО вашего комментария :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Stepan Kasyanenko (в комментариях) за идею!
Сформировал bat-ник, который мониторит раз в секунду наличие определенного файла, потом пытается его переименовать (если не может переименовать, значит файл еще занят создающим его процессом), потом перемещаю его в папку "copy" и оттуда уже запускаю его, продолжая после чего мониторить исходную папку.

```
:test
if exist d:\1\napravlenie.doc goto go 
timeout 1
goto test 
:go 
rename d:\1\napravlenie.doc napravlenie.doc
if not errorlevel 0 goto go
:rename
move d:\1\napravlenie.doc d:\1\copy\napravlenie.doc
if errorlevel 1 (
    timeout 1
    goto rename
)
d:\1\copy\napravlenie.doc 
goto test
```